# AppFabric Client version mismatch

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I want to be able to use AppFabric Distibuted Cache. I'm getting the following error:

> ErrorCode:SubStatus:Check the client version. It
>   should be within the allowed version range on the server. If
>   necessary, upgrade the client to the allowed version.

The version of `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client` and `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core` dlls that I'm using is 1.0.4632.0 which is the same dll that I found in AppFabric 1.1 installation directory. Why do I keep getting this error even though I am using the very same dlls that are on the server?

Comment: I just ran up a quick test using the Nuget `ServerAppFabric.Client` package which installs the 1.0.4632.0 client DLLs for you, and it worked fine for me against a 1.1 cache. Are you sure it's the client DLLs that are the problem, or could it be the server version?

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of this error the allowed versions should be configured on the server.

This command should be run on the server in AppFabric configuration Powershell:

```
Update-CacheHostAllowedVersions -EndClientVersion 3
```

I'm not yet sure if this is per host or per cluster.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh343304%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

The longer story behind this is that I discovered I had AppFabric 1.0 on the server (for some reason WebPI installs 1.0 instead of 1.1 which was a little bit unexpected). I was getting this error having 1.0 version, and concluded that upgrading the server would make it dissapear. However doing a simple updgrade is not enough to make it work.